# ggplot2 custom scale color labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have

```
norm.values<-data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), col=rnorm(100), size=sample(c(1,2,3), 100, replace = T))

ggplot(norm.values , aes(x=x, color=col, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(size)), size=3 ) + 
  scale_color_gradient2(low="blue",mid="blue", high="red") + 
  xlab("chi lab") + 
  ylab("psi lab") +
  labs(color = "Kolor Lab" )+
  labs(shape = "Size Lab", size=20) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=16), legend.text=element_text(size=18), strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14), strip.text.y = element_text(size = 14),  legend.title =   element_text(size = 18))
```

In the color legend `Kolor Lab` I would like the label for red to be `>2`instead of `2` .
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `breaks` and `labels` argument of `scale_color_gradient2`:

```
ggplot(norm.values , aes(x=x, color=col, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(size)), size=3 ) + 
  scale_color_gradient2(low="blue",mid="blue", high="red",
                       breaks=c(2,1,0,-1,-2),
                       labels = c(">2", "1", "0", "-1", "-2"))+
  xlab("chi lab") + 
  ylab("psi lab") +
  labs(color = "Kolor Lab" )+
  labs(shape = "Size Lab", size=20) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=16), legend.text=element_text(size=18), strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14), strip.text.y = element_text(size = 14),  legend.title =   element_text(size = 18))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the `labels` argument in your color scale. Just make sure you have a matching `breaks` argument too.

```r
ggplot(norm.values, aes(x, y, color = col)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = factor(size)), size = 3) + 
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "blue", high = "red",
                        breaks = seq(-2, 2), labels = c(-2, -1, 0, 1, ">2")) +
  labs(shape = "Size Lab", x = "chi lab", y = "psi lab", color = "Kolor") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 18, hjust = 1))
```

[image]